# Project structure for a src to dist folder using node_modules

Tags: node.js, node-modules, project-structure

I'm working on an project that makes use of npm's `node_modules`. In my case it's an Angular 2 project with Typescript, but I don't think that relevant.

My project structure looks like this:

```
/
  dist/
    main.js
    index.html
  node_modules/
    ** all node modules
  src/
    main.ts
    index.html
```

The sources are in the `src` folder, and everything is automatically copied to the `dist` folder on save (Grunt tasks).

The only problem is, how do I reference the `node_modules` from the `index.html` file?

I could put a `../` in front of the path of every script that I reference in the `index.html`. But in a production environment the `index.html` will be in the root directory like the `node_modules` folder is. That means I have to update all the style and script references and remove the `../` infront of all paths.

I have the feeling there is a better way to setup my work environment. I couldn't find any pleasing examples.

How do other projects do this? Is there some sort of a uniform standard that seems to work well?

Comment: Why do you need to reference your node_modules folder?This is the folder where you keep the modules downloaded from external sources and I believe you just require modules such as e.g `var fs = require('fs');` and theoretically you should be able to use them. For your own modules you should have them in src folder.

Comment: @Tomas I'm referencing `angular2.js` in my `index.html`. This library is downloaded into the `node_modules` folder.. I have the feeling that you are talking about a NodeJS script?

Comment: I have exact same issue. Have you found a solution? If yes, I'd appreciate very much if you post an answer or at least give a hint. Thanks!

Comment: Ask Grunt to rewrite the links https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-connect-rewrite